# Extract jquery mobile's function for clearable text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, textbox, imageicon

[Screenshot of What i need exactly.](http://awesomescreenshot.com/09a2n0zxab)
[image: <br>]

I have implemented a mobile website. But I have used normal JQuery v1.7.2 for this.
Now I am facing a problem that I am not able to make a clearable textbox which supports and works well in all devices. 
I tried using [clearableTextField](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=ww59yq-WrcJfUv2W42Xj9IEX3B4&cid=Av7x0X6EEHg&s=&fp=48139&mp&projSelected=true#L0) plugin.

This is working fine when i take my mobile site in desktop browser. But when I take the mobil site in mobile device it works only if I didnt change the orientation of device. While tilting the device the position goes somewhere.
And if I fix the same in android it does not work in iOS devices (sometimes it is working and sometimes it is not)

After all, I started checking all the examples I got. And the only one working is http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/ 
**Is it possible to extract the function alone from it ?**

*Here is the code in jQuery mobile js file.*
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

    $.widget( "mobile.textinput", $.mobile.textinput, {
        options: {
            clearBtn: false,
            clearBtnText: "Clear text"
        },

        _create: function() {
            this._super();

            if ( !!this.options.clearBtn || this.isSearch ) {
                this._addClearBtn();
            }
        },

        clearButton: function() {

            return $( "<a href='#' class='ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" +
    "' title='" + this.options.clearBtnText + "'>" + this.options.clearBtnText + "</a>" );

        },

        _clearBtnClick: function( event ) {
            this.element.val( "" )
                    .focus()
                    .trigger( "change" );

            this._clearBtn.addClass( "ui-input-clear-hidden" );
            event.preventDefault();
        },

        _addClearBtn: function() {

            if ( !this.options.enhanced ) {
                this._enhanceClear();
            }

            $.extend( this, {
                _clearBtn: this.widget().find("a.ui-input-clear")
            });

            this._bindClearEvents();

            this._toggleClear();

        },

        _enhanceClear: function() {

            this.clearButton().appendTo( this.widget() );
            this.widget().addClass( "ui-input-has-clear" );

        },

        _bindClearEvents: function() {

            this._on( this._clearBtn, {
                "click": "_clearBtnClick"
            });

            this._on({
                "keyup": "_toggleClear",
                "change": "_toggleClear",
                "input": "_toggleClear",
                "focus": "_toggleClear",
                "blur": "_toggleClear",
                "cut": "_toggleClear",
                "paste": "_toggleClear"

            });

        },

        _unbindClear: function() {
            this._off( this._clearBtn, "click");
            this._off( this.element, "keyup change input focus blur cut paste" );
        },

        _setOptions: function( options ) {
            this._super( options );

            if ( options.clearBtn !== undefined &&
                !this.element.is( "textarea, :jqmData(type='range')" ) ) {
                if ( options.clearBtn ) {
                    this._addClearBtn();
                } else {
                    this._destroyClear();
                }
            }

            if ( options.clearBtnText !== undefined && this._clearBtn !== undefined ) {
                this._clearBtn.text( options.clearBtnText )
                    .attr("title", options.clearBtnText);
            }
        },

        _toggleClear: function() {
            this._delay( "_toggleClearClass", 0 );
        },

        _toggleClearClass: function() {
            this._clearBtn.toggleClass( "ui-input-clear-hidden", !this.element.val() );
        },

        _destroyClear: function() {
            this.widget().removeClass( "ui-input-has-clear" );
            this._unbindClear();
            this._clearBtn.remove();
        },

        _destroy: function() {
            this._super();
            this._destroyClear();
        }

    });

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use

```
<input type="search">
```

? In compliant browsers it just plain works. I believe the support is pretty good on mobile.

Comment: i tried. It is not showing any icon at the last/first part of the textbox in my iPod device. And one doubt : won't it show different images in different devices. ?

Comment: So yes - every browser can render input type=search a bit differently. However, it will be consistent for the device itself, which is what you want anyway. To ensure you didn't do anything wrong, open nativeformelements.com on your browser. This is a cool site that gives you a demo of all the different form types. See if it looks right there.

Comment: Well, thanks for the update. Checked the site in device. The type=search box is not showing x icon in my iPod device !! So at any cost i will have to try something else.

Comment: Now I am sticking on my question again. Is it possible to extract from jquery mobile script ?

Comment: query - did you try typing first? I know in Chrome you don't get the X until you type something. Hmm, yeah, in iOS it doesn't work at all it seems. Sorry!

Comment: Even in android it doesnt work (from nativeformelements.com) in old mobile devices. But checked in MotoG and works fine.